# ASP.Net C# Where ID equals Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I have this statement:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Comments SET Flagged = '" + "Yes" + "' WHERE Comment_ID ='" + Row.Cells[0] + "'", con);
```

Visual Studio is underlining Row.Cells[0] saying Row does not exist in current context.

Could you take a look and see where I am going wrong.

Full method Code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

       GridView1.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(GridView1_RowCommand);
        if (e.CommandName == "cmdFlag")
        {
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Comments SET Flagged = '" + "Yes" + "' WHERE Comment_ID ='" + Row.Cells[0] + "'", con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Redirect("~/renteronly/flagset.aspx");
        }
}
```

Comment: `int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.Rows(index);` Have  a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Row is not a member of RowCommand's EventArgument.

Answer (score 1):

Mark, you need to bind **CommandArgument** property with **Comment_ID**.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.CommandName == "cmdFlag")
      {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Comments SET Flagged = 'Yes' WHERE Comment_ID = @Comment_ID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_ID",e.CommandArgument);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("~/renteronly/flagset.aspx");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Hiya I have set it like this but it does not update the table at all just goes to flagset.aspx

Comment: @Jan-Frederik How would I go about binding it?

Comment: @Jan I have done this - <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" 
            CommandArgument="Comment_ID" Width="798px">

Comment: Thanks for markup, you should write: CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Comment_ID") %>' because it has to be bound from datasource

Comment: @Jan Hiya I added that but get the error - Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: @Mark Hi Mark, I overlooked that, you have to use the property in the control within the GridView that also has the commandName-property. This could be a button, LinkButton etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected row like GridView.SelectedRow.